# How to write a code such that if we change in 'moodle' password, and it automatically update password in 'joomla'?

Tags: database, joomla, moodle

what are the possible ways to do this ?
Is it possible to have common database for both?
P.S.- beginner web developer

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Joomdle](http://www.joomdle.com/)? You don't have to write any code. Joomdle already have these features. Just read their documentation. Install [Community Builder](https://www.joomlapolis.com/) than after that map the fields of joomla to moodle and it will automatically sync accounts from joomla to moodle (vice versa).